Authentication of users in Azure AD B2C inside a Modal instead of a page
Is it possible to authenticate a public customer inside a modal using Azure AD B2C instead of a page?
The App is a React based App (NextJS).

For a simpler sign-up or sign-in experience, you can avoid redirecting users to a separate sign-up or sign-in page, or generating a pop-up window. By using the inline frame  HTML element, you can embed the Azure AD B2C sign-in user interface directly into your web application.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/embedded-login?pivots=b2c-custom-policy
IMPORTANT NOTE
Embedded sign-up or sign-in supports local accounts only. Most social identity providers (for example, Google and Facebook) block their sign-in pages from being rendered in inline frame
